# How to source my .bashrc from a shell script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script `script.sh` which contains the following line:

`sudo -u myusername sh ~/.profile`

From a shell I am able to just call `source ~/.profile` but that does not work in a script and this command does. It forces my current shell to read my `~/.profile`

However, my `~/.profile` contains the following lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

As it is supposed to source my `~/.bashrc`.  But, when I run `script.sh` I get the following error:

`/home/username/.profile: 24: /home/username/.profile: source: not found`

Is it possible to source my `~/.bashrc` file from my `~/.profile` (which is itself being called from another script) without changing either my `~/.bashrc` or my `~/.profile`?

This `script.sh` downloads my `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` file and puts them in the right place, so I want to source those files from within `script.sh` once they are downloaded and have them affect the shell session which I used to run `script.sh`

Answer (score 6):

The error comes from trying to execute the `~/.profile` file with `sh`, which does not understand `source` (`sh` uses `.` (dot) instead, which also works in `bash` and all other POSIX shells).

Furthermore, executing `~/.profile` will not set the environment variables that this file sets in the shell that executes it.  This is because it runs in its own subshell.

A child shell (which is what you get when you execute `~/.profile` rather than sourcing it) will never affect the environment of the parent shell (the shell that you execute the script from). You can therefore not set variables in `~/.profile` and expect them to then be set in your script unless you `source` the file.

Running `sudo source ~/.profile` will not help here as `sudo` will be a child process of the current shell.

---

Related, extra information:

To set up the environment for a script that is not run from an interactive shell (where `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` are already sourced), set the `BASH_ENV` variable to the appropriate file upon invoking the script. This will make `bash` source the `$BASH_ENV` file before handing control over to your script.

For example:

```
BASH_ENV="$HOME/.profile" "$HOME/scripts/myscript.sh"
```

This is *only* necessary if invoking the script from a non-interactive shell session, such as a cron job, and if you need to access environment variables set up in `~/.profile` or any file that `~/.profile` sources.

From an interactive shell session, the `BASH_ENV` variable does not have to be set in this way, and the script does not need to source `~/.bashrc`  nor `~/.profile` since these have already been sourced.

Comment: I updated my question.  Those files do not exist prior to me running `script.sh` - will this still work?

Comment: @Startec No, the file has to exist. The main error is that you are trying to execute a script written for `bash` with `sh` though.