# Is it possible to source ~/.profile in the current shell from a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, profile

Take the following `~/test.sh` script as an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u ${SUDO_USER} cp ~/.profile ~/.profile.bak

cat <<EOF >>/home/${SUDO_USER}/.profile
export HELLO="Hello StackExchange"
EOF

sudo -u ${SUDO_USER} source ~/.profile

sudo -u ${SUDO_USER} cp ~/.profile.bak ~/.profile
sudo -u ${SUDO_USER} rm ~/.profile.bak
```

I then run it like this:

```
User@MACHINE:~$ sudo bash test.sh
User@MACHINE:~$ echo $HELLO
```

I was expecting `Hello StackExchange` to be printed on the terminal, but a blank line was printed instead.

If I understand what's happening correctly, the `source ~/.profile` command is not being applied to my current shell. So how I can source changes done to files like `.profile` to the current running shell from a script without having to logout and log back in? Is this even possible?

P.S: Assume `test.sh` is always ran with `sudo` and never without it. The script above is just an example, but I use `sudo -u ${SUDO_USER} command` when I need certain commands to run as the user who invoked the script and not as `root`.

Comment: Why are you using SUDO_USER with su?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Not sure what you mean...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro When I run `sudo bash test.sh` the user inside the script will be `root` and `$SUDO_USER` gives me my username `Ricardo` which I need to specify the user I want `su` to run with. I'm in the process of replacing the `su` calls with `sudo`, makes for clearer commands (I'll edit the question in a few seconds). But the problem persists

Comment: That is expected sudo behaviour

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I understand that, but I'm not trying to workaround that. I'm just asking a question and posted what I tried, I'm no expert and I'm probably going wrong about this. Thus the question here :)

Comment: See the duplicate. It got nothing to do with source, but with sudo behaviour, if I am understanding the question. Abraços.

Comment: You seem to be working on the same thing as in this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437872/how-to-source-my-bashrc-from-a-shell-script  See my answer there.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm confused by the answer on that question. In other words, are you saying it's not possible?

Comment: Exactly. In your case, twice impossible.  You will not get the `HELLO` variable in your script, and it will furthermore not be available in the shell that you run your script in.  You would have to `source` your script, and your script would have to source the file that defines the variable.

Comment: @Kusalananda "You would have to source your script, and your script would have to source the file that defines the variable." You say this like it's possible, but I guess it isn't? The whole point of this was to make an "installation script" for my machines where I didn't require to manually source files or to force a manual shell restart. But I guess this just ain't possible.

Comment: With the way your are running the script, and the way you are reading the `~/.profile` file in the script right now, it's not possible.

Comment: @Kusalananda How would I have to run the script and read `~/.profile` in the script to make it possible? That's basically my question.

Comment: I have already said how: "You would have to `source` your script, and your script would have to `source` the file that defines the variable."